# Sequelize AND condition object

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I wanted to return field which matches all the query params using $and. It will only return true if it maches formId, respondent and receipient. How do we do this using $and in sequelize?. All must be true to return a result. Thank you.

```
 const Request = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    query: {
      formId: 2,
      respondentId: 252,
      recipientId: 197,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did `where` not work?

```
 const Request = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: {
      formId: 2,
      respondentId: 252,
      recipientId: 197,
    },
  });
```